# LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE replacement for InnoDB? MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

Is there a way to force index into cache for InnoDB tables?

The problem is I don't have enough memory to load all indexes into memory, so I want to cache particular ones.

Comment: You want to load them before you need them, or you want to keep others from loading and replacing the ones already in memory?

Comment: I just want to speed up selects that use index (even the first ones, so yes I want them before I need them), 'load index into cache' makes them work 10x+ faster, but tables' engine is InnoDB, I don't know why it works and want something 'compatible' with MySQL manual... (my table has tens of millions of rows...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading the primary key (clustered) index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name
```

Loading secondary index:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name FORCE INDEX(key_name)
```